# Why switching from Heisenberg picture to Interaction does not change the (Lorentz) transformation law of fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In his book, The theory of quantum fields, Weinberg builds the most general interacting picture (i.e. free) field by listing all possible Poincarè representation.

These fields change so that, if we denote with $U_0$ the "free" Poincarè representations, $U_0(\Lambda,a) \psi(x) U_0(\Lambda,a)^\dagger = D(\Lambda) \psi(\Lambda x + a)$.

Now if $\Psi(x)$ is the Heisenberg picture field, why can we say that

$U(\Lambda,a) \Psi(x) U(\Lambda,a)^\dagger = D(\Lambda) \Psi(\Lambda x + a)$,

if we know that the theory is Lorentz invariant, that is $[U_0(\Lambda,a),S] = 0$, where $S$ is the scattering operator defined in chapter 3?

Thank you in advance for any insight.